# $scope is not refreshing data in template

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
            PublishMessageService.viewPublishMessage(postId).then(function(d){
                if(d.data.post) {
                    $scope.showPost = true;
                    $scope.post = d.data.post;                          
                    $scope.showContentLoading = false;
                    ShareObjectService.setPostPhotoIds($scope.post.photosIds);
                    debugger
//                  $scope.$apply();
                } else {
                    showInlineMessage(Utils.prepareErrorMessage("Nothing Was Found", "Sorry requested content is not available."));
                }               
            }, function(err) {
                showInlineMessage(Utils.prepareErrorMessage("Sorry!", err.description));
            });
```

Here i am getting data for `$scope.post` but its not reflecting in template. If i use `$scope.$apply()` the i gett error `$scope.$apply is not a function`. I dont know why suddenly i start getting this kind of problem. earlier it was working fine.

Comment: can you show all code from controller, or at least the $scope definition?

Comment: please show more, how is $scope injected?

Comment: From code it looks like you are going to implement $scope.$apply in service rather than in controller. Better broadcast data to the controller. Use **$scope.$apply(function(){$scope.showPost = true;
                    $scope.post = d.data.post;                          
                    $scope.showContentLoading = false;})** rather than all data to bind again.